# How to display Products from a certain Category in Magento (without subcategories)

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

I have a Category X with two subcategories Y and Z. X also has one Product bound to it.
When I try to select the Products like this:

```
$category_obj->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category_obj);
```

I get all Products in X plus the ones in the Subcategories.

Is there are way to get only the product/s in Category X?

Thanks in advance,
Rho

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it will display the expected result what u are getting now because you are filtering by $Category_obj. Why dont u filter products by category

you need to do something like this :- 
Fetch The Needed Category's Id from category_obj and Then do this :-

```
$category_obj->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category_id);
```